# Browserify javascript library work well on iOS simulator but real device

Tags: javascript, ios, browserify

I have a browerified javascript lib that works very well on simulator, just  I use iOS WKWebview to evaluate it but on real device it doesn't. Somehow it cannot make any request to the server side. The device connected to the same network with the simulator.
Is there anyone has faced this problem?

Updated:
index.html

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
                <meta name="description" content="">
                    <script src="bwc.js"></script>
                    <script src="wallet.js"></script>
                    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Swift code:

```
if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "index", ofType: "html") {
            webView.loadFileURL(URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath), allowingReadAccessTo: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filePath))
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your Transport security, it needs to allow your url

Comment: I did set the "Allow Arbitrary Loads" to YES.

Comment: I put it to YES at the beginning, and it did help.

Comment: and you have no error? just does not work? where is your console log?